# Change a "\" to a "/"

Tags: java, string, backslash, slash, replaceall

I'm looking for a simple piece of code that will change all the backslashes in a string to forward slashes using java.

I tried this:
word.replaceAll("\","/");

but it will not work. Anyone have a quick fix for this?

Thanks

P.S.
I also just noticed that pretty much none of my string operations are working. I tried things like toUpperCase() and nothing happened to the string?!?

Comment: The String class is immutable so it never changes. It always returns a new copy with the changes made.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`replaceAll()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) is the **wrong** method to use in this case, because it uses [regular expressions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression) to match.

You want the simpler [`replace()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace%28char,%20char%29) method that replaces literals. Try this:

```
word = word.replace("\\","/");
```

Notes:

1. You have to escape the backslash with another backslash, ie `"\\"` is how you code a String that is a single backslash
2. String are [immutable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immutable) - String methods return a *new* String with the result... they don't *change* the String. That's why you need to code it like `myString = myString.someMethod();`

Answer (score 4):

the functions will return a new string with the changes you are trying to implement not change the string itself. in the `\` case you may need to use an escaped slash ( `\\` )

Comment: sorry, thats what I meant to type in the original question, so the function i used was: word.replaceAll("\\","/");

Answer (score 1):

In this case you would need to use:

```
word.replaceAll(("\\", "/");
```

`toUpperCase()` **returns** a string, it does not change the string calling the method.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/String.html

Comment: Oh! that's my problem I believe. I need to do word = word.replaceAll("\\","/") thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Strings are **immutable**.
They can never change.

You need to write `word = word.something()`.

Answer (score 1):

all you need to do is word = word.replaceAll("\", "/");

you have to know that a string can't be changed.

those methods work by iterating over the characters of the string and replacing all the backlashes with forward slash